# Phpmyadmin fails to import sql files

Tags: phpmyadmin

I exported all tables from my database with the option **"Export tables as separate files"**.

This worked perfectly, the tables were packed to a zip file:

[image]

However, If I try to import them, I get this:

[image]

and nothing is imported:

[image]

I also tried to remove `botecsql10_database.sql`, `botecsql10_extra.sql` and export it again. This is to make sure that only files with "table" in the name are imported.

But then I get this:

[image]

But only a single table was imported

[image]

How can I import the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up to try to import the single tables. I solved it by exporting the database as a compressed .zip file. I omitted very large log tables.

Then I uploaded the file to the server where MySQL runs and imported the compressed database dump via the following mysql command after extracting it:

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p target_database < dump.sql
```

Phpmyadmin is not a good candidate for importing databases, always import/export directly on the database server by using commands.